# Find and then show/hide an edje part

Tags: c, tizen

I have a Tizen Edje file which defines my layout.  One part is an image with part name 'warning'.  The item is set to visible in the edge file, and it shows as expected.

I want to hide this part using C code:

```
Evas_Object* image_NotSetYet = (Evas_Object *) edje_object_part_object_get(elm_layout_edje_get(wid->edjeLayout), "warning");
if (image_NotSetYet == NULL) {
  dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "View: Unable to get warning image part");
  return;
}
evas_object_hide(image_NotSetYet);
```

I have tried many different ways to get the Evas Object associated with this part name and hide it.  After many hours I stumbled onto some code that I modeled after, and it seems to work.  I can hide (and show) my image part now.

However, I later add an unrealted image to a swallow in this layout and show it.  All of a suddent the 'warning' part image shows again.  Why?  Am I hiding the 'warning' part the wrong way?  Is there something wrong with the above?

Alternatively, is there something wrong with the way I am adding an image to the swallow below?  The image (from file) will show up, but suddenly my warning part above shows too:

```
Evas_Object *img = elm_image_add(wid->edjeLayout);
if (img == NULL) {
  dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "View: Failed to add a image.");
  return;
}

// Create an image and set contents to imagefile
char *imageFileName = barcode_filename();
bool isSet = elm_image_file_set(img, imageFileName, NULL);
dlog_print((isSet?DLOG_INFO:DLOG_ERROR), LOG_TAG, "View: %s file [%s] to image",(isSet==EINA_TRUE?"Set":"Failed to set"),imageFileName);
free(imageFileName);
evas_object_show(img);

// Assign the image to the swallow2 part
elm_object_part_content_set(wid->edjeLayout,"swallow2",img);
```

I tried adding the image to the 'window' instead of the 'layout' but that didn't seem to matter.  (I've seen many contradictory examples so I don't know which is right)
I tried setting the image to the 'swallow2' part name many different ways (again, many contradictory ways show).  Is this the problem?
Otherwise, can someone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The image_NotSetYet is not an image object.

```
Evas_Object* image_NotSetYet = (Evas_Object *) edje_object_part_object_get(elm_layout_edje_get(wid->edjeLayout), "warning");
```

That refers to the "warning" swallow part object.
[You should never modify the state of the returned object, because it's meant to be managed by Edje, solely.](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/tizen-iot-headed/4.0/group__Edje__Object.html#ga2dddbefbc9ad1aa4d656e0ad002364a2)

If you want to get the image pointer from your layout as you expected, you could use following instead.

```
Evas_Object* image_NotSetYet = elm_object_part_content_get((wid->edjeLayout), "warning")
```

But as above [link](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/tizen-iot-headed/4.0/group__Edje__Object.html#ga2dddbefbc9ad1aa4d656e0ad002364a2) describes, the image object should be manged by Edje.
You might got the 2nd problem because it is managed by Edje. So please use [edje_object_signal_emit](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.ui.practices/html/native/efl/edje_message_signal_n.htm) to handle swallowed images.